# What is the size of the Backtracking Tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree, backtracking, n-queens

**Does anyone know how did we get answer for part (b)?**

Below is an internal node in the backtracking tree for the 6 queens problem. (a)
Show the next solution that the program will discover.

[image]

(b) Use the above conguration to estimate the size of the backtracking tree (i.e., assume that
the random experiment ended at the above left conguration).

**ANSWER:**

Estimate = 1 + 6 + 6 * 3 + 6 * 3 * 1 + 6 * 3 * 1 * 1 + 6 * 3 * 1 * 1 = 97.

Another example is in page 9 [Here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Elila/anis.pdf)

Comment: The link is dead. Also the equation in the example is incorrect (the left-hand side evaluates to `79`). Also, the config on the right is not a solution for the n-queens problem: left-most and right-most queen are on the same row. Maybe the queens are only allowed to threaten diagonally in your example? This is not specified. It's not clear if you are asked to give the size of the tree required to reach the left config, the size of the tree to reach the right config, or the size of the tree required to go from the left to the right. But in all cases, both `79` and `97` seem too small to me.

Comment: Additional note: If the queens are only allowed to threaten diagonally, then the right config is not the earliest solution that will be found from the left config. Starting from the left config and placing a queen at the top-right corner, I only have to move it two positions down to reach a config where no pair of queens are threatening each other. So the example does not make any sense.